# how to copy multiple files to a directory and simultaneously enter in that directory?

Tags: copy

I am trying to write a bash function in my .bashrc which copy multiple files in a directory and enter it, the problem is that it copies the files but do not enter the directory and says:"omitted directory"
cpcd() `if [ -d "${!#}" ]
         then 
            cp  "$@" "${!#}" && cd "${!#}" && ls 
         else
             print "last argument is not a directory or does not exist"
         fi`

Comment: Please format the code using the code icon { } above the edit question window.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
cp "$@" "${!#}"
```

that has the effect that the last argument (the directory name) is repeated.

So, I think what you want is probably this instead (just remove the `"${!#}"`):

```
cp "$@"
```

The other issue is that you say it does not enter the directory. A script that you just execute normally will not change your current working directory; if you want that to happen you need to source the script instead. So, instead of running it like this:

```
./yourscript.sh [arguments]
```

you would then source it, like this:

```
. yourscript.sh [arguments]
```